# how to add jar dependency to xtext maven build

Tags: maven, xtext, maven-dependency-plugin

What is the correct way to use a maven jar file in my xtext dsl project?

What I have tried is this:

- use the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) in the `pom.xml` file of the `*.dsl` project to download the `.jar` file from a maven repository into the `./lib/` directory. This is done as early as possible in the build process: in the maven [validate phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)
- in `MANIFEST.MF`: add the jar to the classpath: e.g. `Bundle-ClassPath: ., lib/value-2.5.6-annotations.jar`
- in `build.properties`: add it to the `bin.includes`

The problem is, that the build only works when I call `mvn install` twice.

The first time, the `.jar` file is downloaded to the `lib` directory as expected (early in the build process), but then the build fails because it cannot resolve the types in my `jar file`.
When I then run `mvn install` again (the `.jar` file now already exists in the `lib` directory before the build), it works fine.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: this is a bug/problem with eclipse tycho e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353889

Comment: and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393978

Comment: @ChristianDietrich
Wow - those bugs are already 5+ years old! Is Buckminster still a build option? I've read about it in the xtext book, but cannot find anything in the current xtext version.

Comment: No. Maybe one of the bugs or linked ones have workarounds

Comment: a simple workaround that I use for now in my CI script is to first execute `mvn verify` (to download the jars) and then call `mvn install`

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Currently it does not work as expected, because of bugs in [Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/)

- [#353889: Defer target&dependency resolution to the normal build](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353889)
- [#393978 maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies goal does not work reliably with Tycho projects - "error copying ....jar.jar"](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393978)

## Long answer

Here is what I did to make it work (for now) in the `xxx.dsl` project:

### pom.xml file

1. I use the [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) to download the jar file in the [maven validate phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) (as early in the build as possible) to the `lib` directory.
2. Note, that I use `stripVersion=true` so that the file in the `lib` dir is called `value-annotations.jar` (and not `value-2.5.6-annotations.jar`). If I ever want to update the version in the future, I only need to update it in one place in the `pom.xml` file.
3. The jar file must also be specified as a dependency, because otherwise the users of the dsl plugin cannot build the project: i.e. the `generateXtext` task of the [xtext-gradle-plugin](http://xtext.github.io/xtext-gradle-plugin/xtext-builder.html) will fail because it cannot find the classes in the jar file.

Relevant `pom.xml` code:

```
<project ...>
    <properties>
        <xtextVersion>2.13.0</xtextVersion>
        <immutablesVersion>2.5.6</immutablesVersion>
        ...
    </properties> 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-libraries</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>value</artifactId>
                                    <version>${immutablesVersion}</version>
                                    <classifier>annotations</classifier>
                                    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        ...
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
            <artifactId>value</artifactId>
            <version>${immutablesVersion}</version>
            <classifier>annotations</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file

1. Add the jar file to the `Bundle-ClassPath`, so that we can use it: e.g. in the `DslJvmModelInferrer.xtend`
2. Add the package of the jar file to `Export-Package`, so that these files can be accessed by the `xxx.dsl.tests` project

Relevant parts of `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: ., lib/value-annotations.jar
Export-Package: xxx.xtext,
 ...
 xxx.xtext.validation,
 org.immutables.value
```

### build.properties file

Add the jar file to the `bin.includes` so that it will be copied to the generated jar file (in the `target` directory):

```
bin.includes=model/generated/,\
               .,\
               META-INF/,\
               lib/value-annotations.jar,\
               plugin.xml
```

### Build

Now the build works in **Eclipse**.

On the **command line** (and in my continuous integration server script), I must execute maven twice (because of the mentioned bugs):

- `mvn verify` (to download the jars)
- `mvn install`